# Dart - Overflow Safe Summation of List

Tags: dart, sum, overflow, integer-overflow

In Dart, is there a simple way to check whether the sum of a list will produce a 'real' value (a value that doesn't overflow or underflow)?

Examples:

```dart
overflowSafeSum([0,1,2]) //3
overflowSafeSum([1,9223372036854775807]) //Over
overflowSafeSum([-1,-9223372036854775808]) //Under
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to dart, this is the best I got right now:

```dart
import 'dart:math' show pow;

enum Overflow {
  over,
  under,
}

void main() {
//idea: Iterate through the elements of a list and add them, 
//each time the sum overflows: increase overflowCounter by 1
//each time the sum underflows: decrease overflowCounter by 1
//if all the elements have been added and the overflowCounter == 0, the sum must be real

  overflowSafeSum(List<int> userList) {
    var sum = 0, overflowCounter = 0;
    for (int index = 0, nextTerm;
        index < userList.length;
        index++, sum += nextTerm) {
      nextTerm = userList[index];
      if (sum.sign != nextTerm.sign) {
        continue; //adding a postive and negative can't overflow or underflow
      } else if (sum >= 0 && nextTerm >= 0) {
        if ((sum + nextTerm) < 0) overflowCounter++;
      } else {
        if ((sum + nextTerm) >= 0) overflowCounter--;
      }
    }
    if (overflowCounter == 0) {
      return sum;
    } else if (overflowCounter > 0) {
      return Overflow.over;
    } else {
      return Overflow.under;
    }
  }
  var myList = [1,0,(pow(2,63)-1).toInt()];
  print(overflowSafeSum(myList)); //Overflow.over
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to decrement the overflow counter.  Once overflow occurs, you can't trust the result, and you shouldn't be able to return to the "normal" state.

Comment: It actually does make sense. It's effectively using `overflowCounter` as bits 64..127 of the result. Now, if you manage to overflow more than 2^64 times, you'll need an extra overflow-overflow integer, but that's ... probably not going to happen in our lifetimes.
Only works for 64-bit integers, not JS-numbers, but it's a reasonable approach for native overflow detection (and it doesn't *fail* for JS-numbers since they never overflow, they might just lose precision).

Answer (score 0):

(To be pedantic: "[underflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow)" is not negative overflow.  Overflow occurs when the *magnitude* of a number is too large to be represented, regardless of sign.  Underflow is an issue with *floating-point* operations where the magnitude of a number is too small (too close to 0) to be represented.)

You can't generally detect overflow with Dart `int`s since Dart for the web is transpiled to JavaScript, where `int`s are backed by JavaScript numbers (IEEE-754 double-precision floating-point values).  If you instead use `Int32` or `Int64` from [`package:fixnum`](https://pub.dev/packages/fixnum) (or if you restrict yourself to the Dart VM), then you could make a helper function like:

```dart
class OverflowException implements Exception {
  OverflowException({this.positive = true});

  bool positive;
}

Int64 checkedAdd(Int64 a, Int64 b) {
  var sum = a + b;
  if (a > 0 && b > 0 && sum < 0) {
    throw OverflowException(positive: true);
  }
  if (a < 0 && b < 0 && sum > 0) {
    throw OverflowException(positive: false);
  }
  return sum;
}
```

From there, you could trivially add a function that calls it in a loop:

```dart
Int64 overflowSafeSum(Iterable<int> numbers) {
  var sum = Int64(0);
  for (var number in numbers) {
    sum = checkedAdd(sum, Int32(number));
  }
  return sum;
}
```

or if you prefer using `Iterable.fold`:

```dart
Int64 overflowSafeSum(Iterable<int> numbers) =>
    numbers.fold<Int64>(Int64(0), (sum, i) => checkedAdd(sum, Int64(i)));
```